# loop through selected row elements JQuery

Tags: jquery

How can i get the content of the selected rows in any table and submit their values in a post array using JQuery ?

Here's my table :

```
            <?php if(isset($products)){ ?>
            <?php foreach( $products as $product){ ?>
                <tr id="<?php echo $product['order_product_id']; ?>">
                    <td class="center"><input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="selected-p[]" value="<?php echo $product['order_product_id']; ?>" /></td>
                    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="order_id" value="<?php echo $product['order_id']; ?>"/></td>
                    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>"/></td>
                    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>"/></td>
                    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $product['price']; ?>"/></td>

                    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="cost" value="<?php echo $product['cost']; ?>"/></td>
                    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="product_cost" value="<?php echo $product['product_cost']; ?>"/></td>
                    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="logistics_cost" value="<?php echo $product['logistics_cost']; ?>"/></td>
                    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="inventory_cost" value="<?php echo $product['inventory_cost']; ?>"/></td>

                    <td class="left"><font  dir="ltr"><?php echo $product['date_added']; ?></font></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

Rendered HTML by question's author:

```
<tr id="39118"><td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name="selected-p[]" value="39118"></td> <td class="left"><input type="text" name="order_id" value="10141"></td> <td class="left"><input type="text" name="product_id" value="881"></td> <td class="left"><input type="text" name="name" value="أساور الصداقة"></td> <td class="left"><input type="text" name="price" value="30.0000"></td> <td class="left"><input type="text" name="cost" value="9.0000"></td> <td class="left"><input type="text" name="product_cost" value="9.00"></td> </tr>
```

Comment: Could you post a representative sample of the rendered HTML? *Not* the php that generates it.

Comment: Basically, multiple rows. each row contains checkbox and some text fields

Comment: Do you mean rows in which the checkbox has been checked?

Comment: Yes , i want to loop over those . and get their content for an ajax post

Comment: Why don't you make it easy on the people trying to help you by posting the rendered HTML in a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
var data = [];

$("#table1 tr").filter(function() {
    return $("td:eq(0) input[type=checkbox]", this).attr("checked");
}).each(function() {
    data.push({
        order_id: $("input[name=order_id]", this).val(),
        product_id: $("input[name=product_id]", this).val(),
        name: $("input[name=name]", this).val(),
        price: $("input[name=price]", this).val(),
        cost: $("input[name=cost]", this).val(),
        product_cost: $("input[name=product_cost]", this).val(),
        logistics_cost: $("input[name=logistics_cost]", this).val(),
        inventory_cost: $("input[name=inventory_cost]", this).val()
    });
});

console.log(data);

if (data.length > 0) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.webpage.com",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Success!! " + data);
        }
    });
}
```

It creates an array called `data` and populates it with objects that represent each row of the table that is ticked.  (Console.log will show you what it gets).

It then performs an ajax call, posting the data and showing any resulting data that is returned.

*(I've made 1 assumption that you need to change to suit.  I've assumed the table has an id of `table1` - see the 2nd line of code.)*

**[Here's a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qHmLb/1/)**

Comment: Whats the filter function for ?! and what does it return ? an array of selected rows ?

Comment: Yes, it only returns the `tr` elements that have a checked checkbox in the first `td`.  It's very useful indeed... http://api.jquery.com/filter/